# DTMF issue with Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: skypedeveloper

I have an application using WebRTC calls with Skype Web SDK.

It looks like DTMF tones are not transmitted when using the Microsoft Edge browser, or not properly understood at their destination.
With Internet Explorer 11, DTMF tones works well.

Is anybody aware of something that is not implemented/incompatible with DTMF and Edge Browser, and also, is there a way to log the DTMF tones on the Skype for Business Servers?

Thank you & Kind Regards
Peter

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.2.15, but I just verified the same behavior with 1.2.36.